# How do I shrink the widgets in a Flutter column to the available size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter `Column` that takes a variable number of timers. When it takes one timer the result looks like I want:

[image: Demo with 1 Timer]

If I however add two timers, I get an overflow:

[image: Demo with 2 Timers that overflows]

I would like in the second case that the timers shrink to take up the available space. If I have four timers it also would ideally show two rows and two columns.

I tried wrapping my Timers with a `FittedBox` that I set to fit: `BoxFit.fitHeight` but that didn't have the desired result. What else do I need to do?

Code with Wrap as it was requested in comments:

```
Wrap(
        children: state.currentTimers
            .map((selectedTimer) => TimerSessionWidget(selectedTimer))
            .toList(),
      );

class TimerSessionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SelectedTimerState createState() => _SelectedTimerState(_selectedTimer);

  final TimerSession _selectedTimer;

  TimerSessionWidget(this._selectedTimer);
}

class _SelectedTimerState extends State {
  final TimerSession _selectedTimer;

  _SelectedTimerState(this._selectedTimer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
          onTap: () {
            if (_selectedTimer.loadedTimerBloc.state is VirginTimerState) {
              _selectedTimer.loadedTimerBloc.add(StartTimerAction());
            } else if (_selectedTimer.loadedTimerBloc.state
                is FinishedTimerState) {
              _selectedTimer.stopAlarmSound();
            }
          },
          child: BlocProvider(
            builder: (context) {
              return _selectedTimer.loadedTimerBloc;
            },
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
              child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        width: 5.0,
                      )),
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: DurationDisplayWidget(_selectedTimer)),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: TimerActionWidget())),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: RemoveTimerWidget(_selectedTimer),
                    )
                  ])),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `Expanded` widget? Or the `mainAxisSize` property of `Column`?

Comment: For to get desired behaviour for your scenario, try using `Wrap` widget without `Column`.

Comment: Playing around with Expanded, mainAxisSize and Wrap didn't get me to successful let the Timer Widget shrink.

Comment: Is there any way you can show us an image of what you would like?

Comment: why dont you want a `ListView`?

Comment: show your codes first how ou have implemented so

Comment: @pskink : I want the Timer to be larger when I only display one Timer then it would be if I use a ListView. I also want all the Timers to be visible without scrolling.

Comment: @OMiShah : I don't see which part of the code that I have written would be helpful to make the question more clear. I went through a few different ways of throwing FittedBox and also widgets like Expanded. I think the images illustrate the issue better.

Comment: @Christian you should consider using ``Wrap`` on your children instead of a column.

If you could post the container code for your timer widget then one could help you accurately but without that it would not be possible for us to help you.

Comment: @OMiShah : I did add code with Wrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your `Column` children under `Expanded`

*"Using an Expanded widget makes a child of a Row, Column, or Flex expand to fill the available space along the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor. "* from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

**Example**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQgQu8nlAEzW63m0pKcq9csbtk-3ni_QlvW4uy6DgeaWbO4Fze1")))),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems the key is that Expanded has to wrap a container and doesn't work when it wraps some other Widgets.